# "Go get it" button directs me to "Ask a question"

Tags: support, badge-progress

Just as the title says, the "Go get it" button redirects me to [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Is this normal?
[image]

Comment: Closed as "*can no longer be reproduced*"? Seriously?

Comment: Well, this is a 10 Feb issue and I can't reproduce it either. It is now 1. April.

Answer (score 6):

That's normal. The Curious badge revolves around asking questions. To earn it, you need to ask *good* questions. Nothing more, nothing else.

Therefore, the text isn't misleading: to *get the badge*, you need to ask a question. Which is exactly what it is linking you to. It's perfectly normal.

Comment: Yes, sorry it seems that I've been confused a little.

Answer (score 4):

The "Curious" badge description is

> Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record.

The "Go get it" button is meant to encourage you to fulfill the requirements for that badge. So, since this badge is all about asking good questions, it's completely intentional that it link you to the "ask a question" page.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't notice that at first. Thank you so much.